# How to use Reflection to inspect the Generic Type of an object?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I need to check if a field of class is a `List<String>`. I've tried to do that with the following code:

```
for (Field formField : formClass.getDeclaredFields()) {    
  ...
  if (formField.getGenericType().equals((Class<List<String>>)(Class<?>)List.class)) {
    ...
  }
}
```

It seems to be a wrong code because `formField.getGenericType().equals((Class<List<String>>)(Class<?>)List.class)` returns `false` even on fields that actually is a `List<String>`.

Another way is to test first if a field is `List` with `formField.getType().equals(List.class)` then check if it's generic with `formField.getGenericType() instanceof ParameterizedType` and at last check class of type arguments.

But I think there is a shorter way to implement this checking. Is there?

Answer (score 4):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    private List<String> strings;
    private List<ReflectionUtils> list;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Class> genericTypes = ReflectionUtils.getGenericType(Main.class);
        for(Class genericType : genericTypes) {
            System.out.println(genericType.getName());
        }
    }
}

class ReflectionUtils {
    public static List<Class> getGenericType(Class clazz) {
        List<Class> genericTypes = new ArrayList<Class>();
        Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
        for(Field field : fields) {
            Class c = getGenericType(field);
            if(c != null) {
                genericTypes.add(c);
            }
        }
        return genericTypes;
    }

    public static Class getGenericType(Field field) {
        Type genericType = field.getGenericType();
        if(genericType instanceof ParameterizedType) {
            ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) genericType;
            return (Class) parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Output from the example:

```
java.lang.String
ReflectionUtils
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com)'s new [TypeToken](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html) class (which will be included in version 12.0... a release candidate for it is currently available in Maven) like this:

```
for (Field formField : formClass.getDeclaredFields()) {    
  ...
  TypeToken<?> type = TypeToken.of(formField.getGenericType());
  if (type.equals(new TypeToken<List<String>>(){}) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Note that this does only work if the class field is actually declared as `List<String>`, not `List<T>` or `ArrayList<String>`. If you want it to match `ArrayList<String>` or any other type that implements `List<String>`, you could do the following check instead:

```
if (new TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
```

It's actually possible to find out if there's a `List<String>` field that is declared as `List<T>` in the declaring class provided the class you're dealing with is a subclass that specifies in its type what `T` is. Take this example:

```
class Foo<T> {
  private List<T> list;
  ...
}

class StringFoo extends Foo<String> { // T is specified in here
  ...
}

TypeToken<StringFoo> stringFooType = TypeToken.of(StringFoo.class);
// iterate through superclasses of StringFoo
for (TypeToken<?> superclass : stringFooType.getTypes().classes()) {
  for (Field field : superclass.getRawType().getDeclaredFields()) {
    // actually resolves T to String for the List<T> field using info from
    // StringFoo's type
    TypeToken<?> type = stringFooType.resolveType(field.getGenericType());
    if (new TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
      System.out.println("List<String> found!");
    }
  }
}
```

There's more information on `TypeToken` available [here](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ReflectionExplained#TypeToken).